# How to go through array of URLs using Curb

Tags: ruby, xpath, curb

I need to parse this page https://www.petsonic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/ and recieve information from every item(name,price,image,etc.). The problem is that i don't know how to parse array of URL. If i were using 'open-uri' i would do something like this

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'


page="https://www.petsonic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/"


doc=Nokogiri::HTML(open(page))
links=doc.xpath('//a[@class="product-name"]/@href')

links.to_a.each do|url|
  doc2=Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  text=doc2.xpath('//a[@class="product-name"]').text
  puts text
end
```

However, i am only allowed to use 'Curb' and that's making me confused

Comment: A) Use `curb` instead of `open-uri`. B) Put these into an array. Hint: Use `map` instead of `each`, that yields what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [curb gem](https://github.com/taf2/curb)

```
gem install curb
```

Then in your ruby script

```
require 'curb'
page = "https://www.petsonic.com/snacks-huesos-para-perros/"
str = Curl.get(page).body
links = str.scan(/<a(.*?)<\/a\>/).flatten.select{|l| l[/class\=\"product-name/]}
inner_text_of_links = links.map{|l| l[/(?<=>).*/]}
puts inner_text_of_links
```

The hard part of this was the regex let's break it down. To get the links we just scan the string for `<a>` tags, then get those into an array and flatten them into one array.

```
str.scan(/<a(.*?)<\/a\>/)
```

Then we select the items which match our pattern.  We are looking for the class you specified.

```
.select{|l| l[/class\=\"product-name/]}
```

Now to get the innertext of the tag we just map it using a look behind regex

```
inner_text_of_links = links.map{|l| l[/(?<=>).*/]}
```

Comment: very comprehensive answer. Thank you,sir :)

Comment: @PTaHHHa thanks but see updated version.  I checked on the link and should be about 26 urls.  We don't need `"|'` in the regex so I removed it.